# PHPMailer not sending e-mail through Gmail, returns blank page

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer, send

I am trying to set up a contact form at the bottom of my page. I am using PHPMailer and trying to receive emails at my gmail account. Every time I submit the form, my url changes to url/email.php and I get a blank page. What am I doing wrong? Can anyone see the glaring error that I am obviously missing?

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <form action="email.php" id="contact-me" method="post" name="contact-me">
          <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">
                <input class="input" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <input class="input" id="email" name="email"
                placeholder="Email" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="input input-textarea" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Type your message here" rows=
                "5"></textarea>
            </div>
            <input name="send" class="send" type="submit" value="Get In Touch">
        </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
require('PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
require_once('PHPMailer-master/class.smtp.php');
include_once('PHPMailer-master/class.phpmail.php');

$name = strip_tags($_Post['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$msg = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
$subject = "Message from Portfolio";

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
$mail->Port = 587;     
$mail->Username = 'me@gmail.com';       
$mail->Password = '***********';

$mail->From = $email;
$mail->FromName = $name;

$mail->AddAddress("me.com", "Katia Sittmann"); 
$mail->AddReplyTo($email, $name);
$mail->isHTML(true); 

$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->Subject =$subject;
$mail->Body = $msg;
$mail->AltBody ="No message entered";

if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message could not be sent.';
  echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  exit;
}else{
   header("Location: thank-you.html");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You are using `isset()`, which will mask any notification about `submit` mismatching the `send` form field.

Comment: try using a try catch and see if it tells you anthing

Comment: So, if I take out the isset() should I use something in it's place? I also tried a try catch and didn't find anything. For awhile the network was throwing an error 500 but I needed to change the port to fix that and have done so. Still getting a blank page and no e-mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got some very confused code here. You should start out with an up-to-date example, not an old one, and make sure you're using the latest PHPMailer (at least 5.2.10).

Don't do this:

```
require('PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
require_once('PHPMailer-master/class.smtp.php');
include_once('PHPMailer-master/class.phpmail.php');
```

All you need is this, which will auto-load the other classes if and when they are needed:

```
require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
```

This won't work:

```
$name = strip_tags($_Post['name']);
```

PHP variables are case-sensitive, so do this:

```
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
```

This will cause problems:

```
$mail->From = $email;
```

When you do this, you're forging the From address, and it will get rejected by SPF checks. Put your own address in here, and let the reply-to carry the submitter's address, as you're already doing.

`Submit` may not be included in the submission if the form is not submitted via that control, e.g. if it's submitted by hitting return in a text input. Check for a field that you know will always be in a submission:

```
if (array_key_exists('email', $_POST)) {...
```

Adding a try/catch will not achieve anything - PHPMailer does not throw exceptions unless you ask it to, and you are not.

You are applying `strip_tags` on the body, but then calling `$mail->isHTML(true);` - do you want HTML or not?

All that said, none of those things will cause a blank page. It's fairly likely you are running into gmail auth problems which are popular lately, and to see that you need to enable debug output:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

and then [read the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) on what you see.

Comment: I was able to get it all sorted out! Thank you for your help! It was indeed an issue with the Gmail authentication problem!